# OSMNX package: osmnx.footprints not working

Tags: python, osmnx

Here is a code that I have seen working correctly for other people, where I try to import building footprints.

```
import osmnx
#osmnx.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
point = (40.719464, -73.993426)
distance = 600
gdf = osmnx.footprints.footprints_from_point(point, distance, footprint_type='building', retain_invalid=False)
```

I don't understand the error I am getting:
I tried playing with the inputs to the function and data types. I run into similar issues when using *footprints_from_polygon*

**The following errors were shown**

```
> IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing
> PredicateError: Failed to evaluate <_FuncPtr object at 0x11865a7a0>
```

Comment: Should be some other issue, because the code runs fine in my environment

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet works fine:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

point = (40.719464, -73.993426)
dist = 600
gdf = ox.footprints_from_point(point, dist, footprint_type='building', retain_invalid=False)
gdf.shape #(2333, 117)
```

If you continue having trouble, try reinstalling OSMnx following the [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#installation).